# How to assign SQL @Action flag in ASP.NET MVC DAL class using single stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, data-access-layer

Here is my SQL query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE User_CRUD
    @Action varchar(20),
    @eno int,
    @ename varchar(50),
    @salary money
AS
    IF @Action = 'Insert'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO employee (eno, ename, salary) 
        VALUES (@eno, @ename, @salary)
    END
    ELSE IF @Action = 'Update'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE employee 
        SET ename = @ename, salary = @salary 
        WHERE eno = @eno
    END
    ELSE IF @Action = 'Delete'
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM employee 
        WHERE eno =@eno
    END
    ELSE IF @Action = 'Getemp'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM employee
    END
    ELSE IF @Action = 'Search'
    BEGIN
        SELECT ename, salary 
        FROM employee 
        WHERE eno = @eno
    END
```

And here is my DAL class file:

```
public int AddEmployee(Models.Employee e1) 
{
        con.Open();
        
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("User_CRUD", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Insert");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eno", e1.Eno);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ename", e1.Ename);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", e1.Salary);
       
        e1.RollNo = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
        return e1.RollNo;
}

public int DeleteEmployee(Models.Employee e1)
{
        con.Open();
        
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("User_CRUD", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Delete");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eno",e1.Eno);
        
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return i;
}

public int UpdateEmployee(Models.Employee e1)
{
        con.Open();
        
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("User_CRUD", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Update");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eno", e1.Eno);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ename", e1.Ename);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", e1.Salary);
        
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return i;
}

public List<Models.Employee> GetEmployee()
{
        List<Models.Employee> li = new List<Models.Employee>();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("User_CRUD", con);
        
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                Models.Employee e1= new Models.Employee();
                e1.RollNo = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                e1.Eno = int.Parse(dr[1].ToString());
                e1.Ename = dr[2].ToString();
                e1.Salary = double.Parse(dr[3].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Getemp");
                li.Add(e1);
            }
        }
        return li;
}

public Models.Employee SearchEmp(Models.Employee e1)
{
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("User_CRUD", con);
        cmd.CommandType= CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Search");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eno", e1.Eno);
        
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                e1.Ename= dr[0].ToString();
                e1.Salary= double.Parse(dr[1].ToString());
            }
        }

        con.Close();  
        return e1;
}
```

When I try to perform some crud operation using single procedure it is showing error in `GetEmployee()` method like `@Action` method which was not supplied. `SearchEmp()` method is also showing the same error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a questionable design practice to have one SP that would do all of these things. As regards to your error: this line `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Getemp");` is clearly in the wrong place, as you are setting a command parameter after `cmd.ExecuteReader()` was called.

Comment: One word of advice - ***DON'T DO THIS!*** It might *seems* like a really smart idea - but **it's not** - not by a long shot. SQL Server will build an execution plan for the stored procedure - based on the first execution - and most likely, this execution plan will be **horribly bad** for all subsequent executions. **Don't do this!** This also blatantly violates the Single Responsibility Principle. You should have **one procedure** for each operation, and only "join" those in your DAL class - not at the database level...

Comment: tried with changing the place of cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Getemp");. But it showing the same error. How can i execute this. Can any one help me this. Thanks

Comment: Where did you put it and what error did you get? You have to update your question to show us what your have tried.

Comment: https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: I think you are also missing `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`.

Comment: I tried with changing the place of cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Getemp"); under the procedure and under the Execute Reader. It is showing the same error like @Action which was not supplied.

Comment: when i try to put cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; it is displaying the error like eno which was not supllied.

Comment: You have to provide exact error messages copy-pasted from wherever they are shown. "it is displaying the error like ..." is not helpful and, frankly, childish. Good luck!

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function 'User_CRUD' expects parameter '@Action', which was not supplied.' ======>This is the error

Comment: Update your original question and show what code combinations you have tried and what errors you got.

Comment: Aside... this is yet another reason why you don't write a single procedure that handles all CRUD operations for an entity. The `@eno`, `@ename` and `@salary` are all declared as mandatory parameters, i.e.: you currently have to supply a value for every one of them even when `@Action` is `Delete`, `Getemp` or `Search`. Have you considered changing their declarations such that they are optional?